# gcc download on windonws ubuntu bash IP address fetch returns error

Tags: c, bash, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've attempted to gcc a test.c file on my windows linux bash subsystem, gives me the "gcc not installed" so i go and try to install gcc using
`sudo apt install gcc`
so i'm using the root "sudo" so permissions should be granted, and i've tried with a few different variations of the install command

When I run the above the command I get the a series of errors saying that the ubuntu site's IP address couldn't be located [(full can be seen here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vhwl.jpg)

I think the Ubuntu server's IP has changed? or moved, I mean it literally gives 404 errors. This what i suspect, I don't know for sure, is there a way to download the gcc compiler? I don't know of any other routes to get the gcc compiler on my bash subsystem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a 404 error (file not found). apt is connecting to the IP in question, it just doesn't have that file. Update your cache (`sudo apt update`), then try installing again.

Comment: @AndreFu just for future reference: don't post "thank you" in the comment section (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you think that he answer was good, please do an upvote, and if you think that the answer gives you a solution to your problem, accept it. That's the way we say "Thank you" here.